# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 when compiling in Mac M2: _libnative_symbols

Tags: c, cmake, shared-libraries, kotlin-native

I am learning C development. I installed CLION IDE trial on MAC OS M2

I exported some .dylib libs from kotlin native and added the following in root folder

```
├── libnative.dylib
├── libnative.dylib.dSYM
│   └── Contents
│       ├── Info.plist
│       └── Resources
│           └── DWARF
│               └── libnative.dylib
├── libnative_api.h
```

I included the libnative.h and wrote some code and compiled them and got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_libnative_symbols", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So, I searched the internet and found that need to link the libs also

So, I added them in the cmake file like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(c_kotln C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 23)
add_executable(c_kotln main.c)
find_library(libnative libnative.dylib PATHS /Users/rageshantonyd/CLionProjects/c_kotln) 
target_link_libraries(c_kotln ${libnative})
```

But when compiling again I still get the above mentioned error:

Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: C/C++ is like JavaScript/Java, C++/Java, C++/C#, they all are completely different programming languages.

Comment: @273K Sorry. I can't get you.

Comment: @273K Kotlin support interoperbilty with C, that is, it is possible to export Kotlin codebase to C

Comment: @273K https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-dynamic-libraries.html#create-a-kotlin-library

Comment: There is no such language C/C++ and CPP is C Pre-Processor.

Comment: You should add `REQUIRED` to your `find_library` call or at least check the value of `libnative-NOTFOUND`